# Set errno value in C

Tags: c, algorithm, error-handling, errno

In a portion of code I need to check if there are some errors on arguments function or if there is a `fscanf` failure.

I have to set the errno value:
I will set errno to `EINVAL` if there are problems with arguments.
But what if i have a failure on `fscanf` ?

Comment: Pick the one that is most suitable from here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Comment: There are *many* [`errno` values predefined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html), pick one which you think matches the best.

Comment: While not exactly addressing your question, note that fscanf has a return value which tells you how many of the parameters in your var args list were successfully assigned to.